# How do you scan two arrays of differing lengths without loop nesting?

Tags: java

The Java problem I'm working on is as follows:

Given two arrays of ints sorted in increasing order, outer and inner, return true if all of the numbers in inner appear in outer. 
The best solution makes only a single "linear" pass of both arrays, taking advantage of the fact that both arrays are already in sorted order.

Does "a single 'linear' pass of both arrays" mean resolving the problem without nesting a second loop?  If not, please explain what a "linear pass" means.

Otherwise, if my interpretation of a "linear pass" is correct, I'm currently at a loss.  The only resolution I've been able to come up with includes a second loop nested beneath the first.

```
public static boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner){
    int trueCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inner.length; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < outer.length; x++){
            if(inner[i] == outer[x]){
                trueCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (trueCount == inner.length);
}
```

Comment: A 'single linear pass' should indicate that you iterate through each array exactly once. That is, there are no nested loops because in the nested scenario you'd be iterating through the second array multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure we'd know how to interpret your homework any better than you. Perhaps asking your instructor would be better?

Comment: Should the values `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` pass your validation check?  There are differing answers and schools of thought on your recommended approach depending on which is acceptable.

Comment: If you're guaranteed there's no *repeating values* then the answer is simple and you only need one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the single linear-pass solution.  Thanks to @Paul Becotte and @Andrw.

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
  int i = 0;

  if(inner.length == 0) return true;

  for(int o = 0; o < outer.length; o++){
    if(inner[i] == outer[o]) i++;
    if(i == inner.length) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't loop the entire length of the inner array...start with the last value checked and just go till you hit a match.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it acceptable etiquette for me to answer my own question with the correct code?  I don't want to take up-votes away from those who helped me because other people searching see my answer at the top.  Yet I'd like to have the correct code in the post in the event I come back to look one day.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation, you're looping over "outer" multiple times (inner.length times), thus  not doing a single pass over each array.

I think you're making this more confusing for yourself than it needs to be. Think of it this way -- while going over one array, you're already keeping track of what index you're at (you use "i" and "x" in your sample code). Why don't you just use one to check both arrays?

Answer is intentionally a little vague as it seems like this is a homework-related question.

Comment: thanks.  not school homework.. self-imposed homework.  I'm using codingbat.com to teach myself the basics of java syntax.  Trust me, before coming here, I spend as much time as possible trying to get the solution.  Turns out it was exhaustion, because the next morning I got it in the first 10 minutes.  with the help of those here of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic interview question.  The optimal answer usually involves a hash table or map. The first pass over the "outer" array goes into the hash table. The second pass over inner just checks to see if the value was already in the table.

```
public static boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner){

    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    for (int o : outer)
    {
        map.put(o, true);
    }

    for (int i : inner)
    {
        Boolean result = map.get(i);
        if ((result == null) || (result.booleanValue() == false))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The code above runs in O(N).

Comment: Since the arrays are sorted, there is no need of `HashMap` here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an answer here that quite works, and it's hard to do without code but I'll try.

I think the trick is to iterate over the larger array (outer) but keep an additional index to the current "Inner" (starting at 0)

As you are going through outer, if the object in the current outer is smaller than the current object in inner, you are okay and just haven't reached the next "inner" yet, so keep going

If the object in the current inner is the same as the object in outer then you're good, you've found a match... you want to increment the inner's index and keep going.

If the object in the current outer is greater than the object in the current inner then you missed one (one of the inner didn't exist in the outer), so you are done--return false.

If you reach the end of the loop then you got through all of them and you know that every one in inner is in outer.

In this way it will automatically skip over "Outer" entries that are not in inner.  the only way to fail out is when one outer is bigger than the current inner, if there had been an outer that was the same as the current inner, you would have incremented inner's index and moved on.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, as I said it's much easier to do with code but I feel really bad entering code for learning-type questions.